# XSD: Options for allowing null values when declaring xs:decimal data types

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd.exe

```
<xs:simpleType name="abc">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Will the tag xs:decimal allows null value or empty value
If not what i have use for this xsd to allow null or empty values

Answer (score 0):

There are two commonly used approaches:

1. Declare a union type where the members of the union are (a) xs:decimal, and (b) a type derived from xs:string with length facet equal to zero.
2. Declare a list type with itemType = xs:decimal and maxLength = 1.

Personally I prefer the second approach, but the first appears to be more common. They are equivalent in terms of validation, but have different effects if you are using data binding technologies, or schema-aware XSLT/XQuery.

Examples of both:

```
<xs:simpleType name="optional-decimal-1">
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:decimal">
    <xs:simpleType base="xs:string">
       <xs:length value="0"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="optional-decimal-2">
  <xs:list itemType="xs:decimal">
    <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
  </xs:list>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Could you explian in brief, what code has to be written ? am very new to XSD